Some examples of noncommutative nil ideal
An ideal $I$ is said to be nil ideal if each of its elements is nilpotent. For example $\lbrace0,2,4,6\rbrace$ is a nil subring of $\mathbb{Z_8}$ but it is commutative, any example of non commutative?

Here's a DaRT query that gets you rings with nonzero, nil Jacobson radicals.

Thanks @rschwieb

Take $R$ to be the ring of $3 \times 3$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $I$ be the ideal of nilpotent matrices of the form
\begin{pmatrix}
0&a&b\\
0&0&c \\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
